# How to reproduce weld Instance behavior on Spring

Tags: java, spring, cdi

I am used to have the

```
@Inject 
Instance<Interface> xxx
```

construction that will inject a new instance of each class that implements the interface. This is very useful because I do not need to know how many or who are these classes in order to instantiate them, and I can iterate them without knowing how many are they.

Now I don't know how to reproduce this behavior with Spring.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The best solution i've found to the moment is to inject applicationContext and

```
@Inject
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

...

Map<String, Object> mapInstance = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring currently supports @Inject as an annotation similar to their @Autowired. You just have to annotate the class to be injected as @Component, @Repository, @Service, or @Controller, or configure the same on Beans.xml.

I suggest you to take a look at the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-collaborators

Comment: Hi. I know spring supports @Inject ... the question is about Instance<>

Comment: You're right... now I understand your question. But I have no idea, sorry. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
@Autowired
private List<Interface> interfaces;
```

In CDI, this would inject a bean of type `List<Interface>`, but in Spring this injects a list of all beans of type `Interface`.

Alternatively,

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Interface> interfaces;
```

will inject a map of all beans of type `Interface` keyed by their bean name.

(When `javax.inject.Inject` is on the classpath, you can replace `@Autowired` by `@Inject`.)